# html Not Found error

Tags: html, https, http-status-code-404, href

I'm just a student of html, and I write just a simple code to learn html..
And I got one question.

If i write code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>html practice</title>
</head>
<body>
    move to <a href=google.com" target="_blank"><strong>google</strong></a>
</body>
</html>
```

this link doesn't work

But when i change my code to     `<a href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank">`, it works very well.

**I don't know why and i'm very curious.. Please help me...**

Comment: You miss doublequotes before `google.com` at `href=google.com"`

Comment: yes I missed it. but if I correct it right, it has same result

Comment: You need atleast the protocol i think

Comment: this way: `move to <a href="http://google.com" target="_blank">`

Comment: *"But when i change my code to `<a href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank">`, it works very well."* - that's because you have the `https://www.` which is required by most browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the http:// or https:// in front of google.com, otherwise the browser will think it is a file held locally on your webserver instead of an external site link.

Comment: Thank you! it is very helpful for me :)

Answer (score -1):

this may be your problem

```
<a href=google.com" target="_blank"><strong>google</strong></a>
```

notice the href??? it is missing the " at the beginning. It should be:

```
<a href="google.com" target="_blank"><strong>google</strong></a>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I got too much help :)

Answer (score -1):

You missed 2 things:
in the href you missed:
- quotes
- http:\
Should be like this:

```
<a href="http:\\google.com" target="_blank">
```

Comment: is 'http' necessary? I don't think it not duty before